# Where is snippet explorer located?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-snippets

I have successfully installed the snippet designer (by Mathew Manela) and had successfully exported my own code snippet once from my VS 2017 by following the instruction from this site:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.SnippetDesigner

However, after I closed the VS2017 and come back and attempted to export another code snippet, I can no longer see the option to export code snippet after I highlighted the code and right clicked on it. 
I wonder where has the functionality gone?

Also I no longer see the snippet explorer, which according to the link, it is located under view->other window. I did see it before I closed the vs 2017 application.

The snippet I originally created worked and is still working though, which amazes me.

I wonder what have I done incorrectly? How do I export another snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally figured out what have I done wrong the hard way.

What I did earlier and probably should not have done was downloading the extension from the link above and clicked on it to install. It downloaded and installed like a champ, no complaint. It even worked for 1 time but then vanished in thin air the next time I got into VS2017. There is no way to find it. Maybe I am not supposed to click on the extension to install it outside of VS2017, but there was no warning or error message, which gave user the false impression that everything was fine.

Now, to fix the issue, I went into VS2017, Tools --> Extension And Updates and pick up the SnippetDesigner from there, re-installed it and closed VS2017 for it to finalize.

Then going back into VS 2017 and everything comes back!

Just posted my experience, hopefully someone else does not have to hit their head against the wall trying to figure out why SnippetDesigner is behaving the way I described above.